# how set orientation of different views?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uiinterfaceorientation

I have one app delegate file and 5 other view.I have connected by navigation controller. now i want to set orientation for landscape mode. i have problem that when i change view then only scoll view change and reamining view and navigation bar and button all not change their postion. While i have set them by xib file but not working. i have below code but that also not work.

```
  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 Return YES;}
```

so now how i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you .... http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

Comment: its not working for all views. it works for only fist view. Next view is not overlap on previous view. navigation bar is shown same as in portrait mode.now how do that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set autoresizing of subviews and as well as statusBar Orientation. You will get many posts on stackoverflow for orientation.